# Autocomplete with PHP, MySQL & jQuery (ajax) not working

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

I'm trying to create a search autocomplete function on my PHP site. I have a SQL table called: posts where new posts are stored. I have an input search field where I would want to list posts by searching their post title, and have them shown asynchronously. I get a 200 response when searching for something in the input field. I do belive that the issue is with displaying the posts after they are fetched from the database.

The server now runs on my XAMP and I've tested with pushing it to a "live" server too. I'm quite new to both jQuery, PHP & SQL so might be a rookie mistake... I haven't pasted all the code from the search input and jQuery files, "just the nesseceiry parts".

Here is the input search field:

```
<form method="GET" class='navbar__search navbar__col'>
    <input type='search' name='navbar__searchField' id="navbar__searchField" placeholder='Search'>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here is the jQuery logic:

```
$("#navbar__searchField").autocomplete({
    source: "../../php/includes/search.php",
    minLength: 1
});
```

And lastly the search.php code:

```
<?php 

// The connection to the DB is done via this require.
require '../core/init.php';

$search = $_GET['navbar__searchField'];
$sql    = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE title LIKE '%$search%'");

if ($sql->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[] = $row['title'];
    }
}

echo json_encode($data); 

$conn->close();
?>
```

At this time I don't get any PHP or network errors. I do get a string at the bottom of the HTML document saying. No search results.

Comment: What does this function do? `sanitizeInput()` . Are you sure that that isn't failing? I'd also try to either remove `method=""` or tell it that it's a GET method. Unsure what that will do left like that. I'd also change the submit input to a button with a submit type.

Comment: sanitize just trims, stirpsslashes and removes htmlspecialchars. I've treid without using the function but to no help

Comment: You don't need all of those additional functions. Just remove that custom function entirely. Then, enable error reporting for the PHP and check for errors on the query with `mysqli_error($conn)` just to cover all the bases, and look at the developer console. You are using this with an HTTP protocol too, right? And not directly in your browser as `file:///`? Also, if it works just on its own (php/mysql), then it would most likely be the JS failing.

Comment: And as I said in my first (edited) comment. Try changing `<input type="submit" value="submit">` to `<button type="submit">Submit</button>`. Inputs with jquery sometimes won't work with inputs. I've seen that often.

Comment: I updated the question from what you said. PHP errors are enabled from the start and I run this on XAMP. The thing I now get is at the lowest level of the HTML document a string is shown after you begin typing: No search results.

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? Do you receive the PHP response you were looking for? Did you debug your JS code?

Comment: I get no JS or PHP errors. When one searches on my website all titles that matches the search phrase should appear asynchronously in the search field. Now when I type something in the field the jQuery runs, the search.php runs but nothing is displayed after searching. The only thing that changes on the site after typing is at the bottom of the HTML document it says: No search results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a test on my machine starting from the [example in the documentation](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote).

If you enter 'word' in the input without pressing the submit button you'll see that this is sent to the server inside a variable named term: the request URL will be http://localhost/search.php?term=word (I really don't know why so far, maybe some JQuery internal). If you change the search variable to `$search = $_GET['term']` the autocomplete will work.

Comment: Ah great thx, I haven't been able to get this to work for the entire day but it worked with just doing what you said, thx! I'll need to research why ['term'] is needed for it to work.